# Take accuracy for simple fit and cross val

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the simple fitting model like this:

```
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = lm.predict(X_test)
print accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
```

and with using cross validation I have this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = model, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 7)
```

from cross validation how can I take the accuracy in order to have the same measure print `accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)`? Is it `accuracies.mean()`?

Comment: do you want accuracy on each cross validation set or the average?

Comment: @PratikKumar I would like both if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print accuracies` will give an array of accuracy on each fold of cross validation

`print "Train set score :: {} ".format(accuracies.mean())` will give the mean accuracy on the cross validation and

`print "Train set score :: {} +/-{}".format(accuracies.mean(),accuracies.std()*2)` will give you the accuracy along with the mean deviation